# jQuery reel Directional mode with sequence not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-reel

am new to jquery Reel plugin, Directional mode with sequence not working, please correct my code

```
<img src="fish/DSCN0691.JPG" width="210" height="186"
  class="reel"
  id="image"
  data-images="fish/DSCN####.JPG|691..702"
  data-directional="true"
  data-frame="3"
  data-opening="1"
  data-delay="3"
  data-speed="1">
```

for each direction it should take 6frames... but its working as normal reel. please correct my code. thanks.

Comment: have you tried changing `data-frame="6"`?

Comment: Yes Jai i have tried... but no luck....

Comment: its working with sprite image, not with sequence images.